# php script to check files if the same exists

Tags: php

I am writing a small php script to check files if the same exists on the Disk's given path,

Currently the scripts reads the file names from the text file(file.txt) and than checks the file in the given path and if the file exists or not it pushes the key/value pair in search result array. 
but the issue is, it shows success only for the last file in file.txt even if all the files exists and even if I give the same filename for all the files.

(though I can accomplish it with other things as well like Batch/Shell, power-shell but just for sharpening the skiills doing it in Php). Not able to understand where I am missing am I doing something wrong while reading the filenames from file.txt.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.
--Sambhav

---

**- File.txt format**

```
file1
file2
file3
```

---

**- PHP Script**

```
<?php
if (ini_get('display_errors') != 1){    ini_set('display_errors',1);    }
$filenames =  file('file.txt');
$path = "D:\testpath";
$search_result = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists($path.chr(92).$filename))

    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File Exists";
    }
    else 
    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File not found";       
    }
}
print_r($search_result);
```

Comment: What code do you have at the minute?

Comment: @Boy Sorry I was modifying the code at the moment, please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another correct script (though script which I have posted in the previous Answer is also working, this is just refinement). In this I have added Trim to trim the whitespace from the array values and also added && is_file($path.chr(92).trim($filename))[suggested by @ArtisiticPhoenix] to check if the filename is not directory

```
<?php
if (ini_get('display_errors') != 1){ ini_set('display_errors',1); }
$filenames =  file('file.txt');
$path = "D:\Ebooks\php";
$search_result = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists($path.chr(92).trim($filename)) && is_file($path.chr(92).trim($filename)))

    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File Exists";
        echo $path.chr(92).$filename."<BR />";
    }
    else 
    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File not found";
        echo $path.chr(92).$filename."<BR />";      
    }
}
print_r($search_result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$path` is not being passed to `checkfile`

try

```
array_walk($filenames,function($filename) use ($path) { 
    return checkfile($filename, $path); 
});
```

---

> but the issue is, it shows success only for the last file in file.txt even if all the files exists and even if I give *the same filename* for all the files.

`$search_result[$filename]` is an associative array indexed by filename, which means it will contain 1 value per unique `$filename`. If you provide duplicate `$filenames` it will simply overwrite the existing value.

If you want to record every check, even for duplicate filenames then don't use an associative array:

```
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists($path.chr(92).$filename))    
    {
        $search_result[] = "$filename Exists";
    }
    else 
    {
        $search_result[] = "$filename not found";       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Fuzzy Tree, Thank you and my sincere apologies as while posting the code here by mistake here I posted the code worng where it wasn't taking the path value. I have reposted the code where I have removed the code completely(and array_walk function in that) but for the last file I am getting the file exists success but for the other files failure and apologies for wasting the time because of my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use the in built php function.file_exists();
ref http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php 
On windows, use //computername/share/filename.
This won't work if PHP has safe_mode enabled. Try setting safe_mode_include_dir to add an exception, and reference the location with the syntax  \computername\share\filename

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, If you see the code mentioned in the question,you will notice that the in built function file_exists is already being used.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter to give a line break in comments and it posted the comment before.

Comment: oh ok i missed that.Can you try to echo $path.chr(92).$filename; and check the path

Comment: hi Jignesh, I already tried that many times and that is coming perfectly correct. As I mentioned the issue is coming to files except the last file (file3 in file.txt mentioned in question) and the last file returns success. The path on printing coming perfectly fine. Even I tried to replace the other filenames with only one filename but than also the success was shown only for the last file.

Comment: @Sambhav I have edited the answer please check 
On windows, use //computername/share/filename.

Comment: Hi Jignesh, Same issue, I tried the n/w path and it works just like before only for the last file not for the others, did it work for you.

Comment: hi Jignesh, I have resolved the issue, I have mentioned in answer to my question, Thanking you for putting you time :)

Comment: I'd forgo using file() and use a stream, that will handle files up to max php integer size ( 2gb on 32bit), other wise your wasting alot of ram pulling the whole file into memory, also file_exists will return true on directories as well as files, so use is_file as well

Answer (score 0):

ok as I suspected the issue where it was reading the filenames from file.txt.
On adding the optional parameter FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES resolved the issue.

file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

So here is the working code if someone is looking for searching the files in given path, of course it could be modified if someone want to use database  stored file names instead of plain text file for input or some other modification depending on the requirement. This is just a basic script which reads the filenames from file.txt and searches for it in given directory provided in $path variable.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
if (ini_get('display_errors') != 1){    ini_set('display_errors',1);    }
$filenames =  file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$path = "D:\testfolder";
$search_result = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists($path.chr(92).$filename))

    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File Exists";
        echo $path.chr(92).$filename."<BR />";
    }
    else 
    {
        $search_result[$filename] = "File not found";
        echo $path.chr(92).$filename."<BR />";      
    }
}
print_r($search_result);
```

**Format of file.txt**

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 0):

um there are no extensions on the filenames? unless i missed something and they are just placeholders ( perhaps the last one is a folder? lol ).

```
    <?php
          ini_set('display_errors',1); //no need to check just turn it on
          $f =  fopen('file.txt', 'r'); //use a file stream
          $path = "D:/testpath/";  //forward slash works windows and linux
          $search_result = array();
          while(false !== ( $filename = fgets($f))) //process 1 line at a time how big will file get?
          {

                  $filename = trim($filename); //always remove whitespace

                    if(file_exists($path.$filename) && is_file($path.$filename))
                      //file_exists returns true on directories 
                   {
                        $search_result[$filename] = "File Exists";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $search_result[$filename] = "File not found";       
                    }
                }
          print_r($search_result);

      fclose($f);
```

-note- code not tested but this is what i would do.

Comment: thank you, yes Issue was with white spaces & the issue was fixed which I had posted in my previous answer. thank you for nice suggestion to check if the file is a regular & not directory. And there are extensions in filename, I had given the file.txt format just for example. I guess there is no use of using a file stream here as the file() already puts the file reading in array, anyway I have posted simpler solution incorporating your trim suggestion and check for file is_file suggestion. thank u for nice suggestions.

Comment: the difference of file() and fgets is that file will read the entire file into memory, and fgets reads only one line into memory, if the file is small, it's not so much of a concern but if it is large, 1 MB or up, i would use fgets, because you will be able to process more data faster, then reading the whole file first.

Comment: also newlines are still an issue in the code i put above, ie empty lines for that you would want to check if(empty( $filename )) continue;